# Irrespective to

Tags: prepositions

It seems that the main preposition for irrespective is of, however, I feel that irrespective to also makes sense. I found it in no dictionary, but according to Google, it seems that it is widely-used. Is that a common mistake or can I use it to convey independence? For example:

> The amount of interestedness in a document is irrespective to the searcher.

Here, by irrespective to, I mean independent from who the searcher is.

Comment: You might find **irrespective to** being used by writers on technical and scientific subjects, or by non-native speakers, but most good writers would not make the statement you have made there. For one thing, its meaning is not clear, and that is a telltale sign that you should avoid it.

Comment: [The results](https://corpus.byu.edu/iweb/?c=iweb&q=66809794) speak for themselves. I don't know how you came up with the idea that *to* makes sense, because *independent to* doesn't (in your sentence at least).

Comment: The idiomatic way to say what you've said is *Who the searcher is has no bearing on the {whatever} of the document.* Or  *The {whatever} of the document is unrelated to who is searching for it.*

Comment: Who is deleting my answers?? Irrespective is always followed by of. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/irrespective%20of Irrespective to would make no sense to me as a native speaker. Anyway, I prefer regardless.

Comment: *interestedness*? Anything wrong with *interest*?

Comment: Your statement "according to Google, it seems that it is widely-used" needs a reference link and some example sentences. Context is necessary to evaluate how it is being used.

Comment: @user3169: Interestedness is used based on the context of my writing. To check with Google, you can search "irrespective to" in Google.

Comment: I could, but that is not the point. The point is you made that claim and should substantiate it. Otherwise it is without merit.

Comment: The entire sentence feels like you're being paid by the syllable, irrespective of clarity ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Irrespective to" is barely used and should probably be considered a mistake or poor phrasing.

Instead there are plenty of clear expressions you can use:

> The amount of *interestedness* is independent of the searcher.

(this is almost what you wrote in your question when you explained what you mean by irrespective to.)

> There is no relation between the searcher and the amount of *interestedness*.

(If the phrasing seems awkward, try turning the sentence round.)